# Unconstrained function minimization when only given samples?

Tags: derivatives, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gradient-descent, hessian-matrix

Let's say we want to minimize a function $f$ of the form:

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)$$

where $x_i$ are samples. One way to solve these types of problem is via identifying a search direction via something like gradient descent. But how do we find the gradient if we are only given discrete function evaluations? Do we approximate the gradient using finite differences? What about the Hessian?

Another approach could be to identify a trust region, or an approximation, utilizing our datapoints. And then solve the approximation for an optimum. But are there any other approaches other than the two main ones of line search and trust region?

Comment: It seems like this function has a recursive definition. Did you mean we have a set of $(x, y)$ pairs $[ (x_i, f(x_i)) ]_{i=1}^N$ and we want to estimate the extrema of $f(x)$?

Comment: Do you mean that the function evaluations themselves are discrete? Meaning we only have a few given datapoints at which we can know the function?